# Make a rule to compile all files .c and link

Tags: gcc, makefile

Make a rule called all to compile and link in once file called "dinam" all files `.c`.

I have tried:

All:
`gcc -c *.c`

I need to kink all `.o` in one file.

Answer (score 0):

This will suffice:

```
dinam:
    gcc -c *.c
    gcc *.o -o dinam
```

You can write more sophisticated makefiles when you are ready.

Comment: duplicate symbol _main in:
    killprocs.o
    rmrubbish.o

Comment: @DiegoPayoMartinez: You have put `main` functions in more than one source file. You must slow down and practice the basics.